# Can I Create FILE Instance by byte[ ] data? (Don't Write file)

Tags: c, linux

Can I Create FILE Instance `(FILE*) by byte[ ]` data (on Memory)? Don't Write file.
(C, Linux)

I Need for 'MiniSEED' format data parsing by [offical MiniSEED Library](https://seiscode.iris.washington.edu/projects/libmseed).

These Library is supported parsing 'MiniSEED' format packet Data that was written in file.

But I Need to parsing 'MiniSEED' data in `Byte[]` array directly. don't create real file.
(because I must get 'MiniSEED' data by realtime TCP Packet, continuously
and These Library support only way to parse data by written file.)

So I try to solve the problem Created `FILE` Instance by `byte[]` data directly.

I think this solution is best way without changing the library as an easy way.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can** create a `FILE` handle from in-memory data in Linux, because the Linux C libraries do support [`fmemopen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) from [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html).

Calling `fmemopen(buffer, size, "r")` yields a read-only `FILE` handle to an in-memory object containing `size` bytes at `buffer`.

However, I don't understand why you'd need such a thing.

[The official Mini-SEED library](https://seiscode.iris.washington.edu/projects/libmseed) does provide function `msr_unpack()` (and `msr_unpack_data()`) to parse Mini-SEED data records.

The functions you are probably looking at using, `ms_readmsr()` and `ms_readtraces()` (or their thread-safe variants `ms_readmsr_r()` and `ms_readtraces_r()`, just read each record from the file, passing each to `msr_unpack()` (and in case of traces, to `mst_addmsrtogroup()` or `mstl_addmsr()`).

In other words, the library does support parsing in-memory data. Your assertion that it only supports parsing files is clearly incorrect.

The man pages describing the library functions do not seem to be available on the net, but if you download [libmseed sources](https://seiscode.iris.washington.edu/projects/libmseed/files), you can read the library function man pages using `man -l libmseed/doc/[function].3`.

Comment: A link to [`fopencookie(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopencookie.3.html) isn't bad as well at this place.

Comment: @glglgl: Sure, with the caveat that it is a GNU extension. `fmemopen()` is POSIX.1-2008, supported by Linux and OpenBSD 5.4 and later, and hopefully others in the future. On the other hand, BSDs (including Mac OS X) have `funopen()`, which is similar to `fopencookie()`; similar enough that a simple wrapper is enough for cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: Just to be clear: I didn't mean to say that the mention was missing, but it can be interesting in this context.

Answer (score 1):

As a compromise, you might use `mmap` to create a direct mapping between the memory and the file. This will allow you to update the contents directly (by accessing the memory) and the library may access the same data through the file interface. Under Unix systems, depending upon the size of the data, the file may not actually need to be written to disk. It may reside in the kernel's cache structure for faster access (this happens by default: nothing extra you need to do).

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no portable, standard way of creating a `FILE *` that represents an in-memory stream of bytes.

The typical solution is to instead make the read and write function(s) hookable, so that instead of hard-coding e.g. `read()` you make the library call an (optionally) application-supplied function.

Comment: There is POSIX.1-2008 and `fmemopen(buf,size,mode)`!